# how to post the choices i check or uncheck in my checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

i want to Edit the box i check or uncheck of my checkbox in the Post controller. This is my code in my Get and in my Cshtml

```
var assignedStudentBadges = db.Enrolled_Students_Badges.Where(x => x.CohortSubscriptionId == id);
            var badges = db.Badges;
            var studentBadges = new List<StudentBadgesViewModel>();
            foreach (var badge in badges)
            {
                var isChecked = assignedStudentBadges.Any(b => b.ID == badge.ID) ? "checked" : null;
                studentBadges.Add(new StudentBadgesViewModel
                {
                    BadgeId = badge.ID,
                    Name = badge.Label,
                    ImageURL = badge.ImageURL,
                    IsChecked = isChecked
                });
            }
            ViewBag.StudentBadges = studentBadges;
            ViewBag.Badges = new SelectList(assignedStudentBadges, "ID", "Label", cohortSubscriptions.Badges);


<div class="">
                                @{ foreach (var badge in ViewBag.StudentBadges)
                                    {
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <img src="@badge.ImageURL" width="80" alt="img-fluid" />
                                            @badge.Name
                                            <input type="checkbox" checked="@badge.IsChecked" id="@badge.BadgeId" />

                                        </div>
                                    }
                                }
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In an input, checked isn't a true or false attribute. You'll need something like

```
@if(@badge.IsChecked)
{
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="@badge.BadgeId" />
}
else
{
    <input type="checkbox" id="@badge.BadgeId" />
}
```

Now. This is a quick example, there are better ways like inline if or @Html.Checkbox

Comment: my get is ok, i have the studentbadge i want from all the badge, it's in the post that i have no idea how to do

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass back whether or not boxes got checked or unchecked on post you can add asp-for to your input. Then you should have access to list items and any changes in your post method. Don't forget to add [BindProperty] annotation to your ViewBag property in your model if you haven't already.

```
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ViewBag.StudentBadges.Count; i++)
    {
        <img src="@Model.ViewBag.StudentBadges[i].ImageURL" width="80" alt="img-fluid" />
        @Model.ViewBag.StudentBadges[i].Name
        <input id="@Model.ViewBag.StudentBadges[i].BadgeId" type="checkbox" checked="@Model.ViewBag.StudentBadges[i].IsChecked" asp-for="@Model.ViewBag.StudentBadges[i].IsChecked"/>
    }
```